# PostgreSQL to MySQL database, error with \xF1o string value

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to migrate a PostgreSQL database to MySQL via MySQL Workbench,
on a Windows PC. The PostgreSQL-driver is in 32 bits for Unicode.
The PostgreSQL is setup in C-encoding, I also tried Dutch encoding.

The MysQL-database is in utf8mb4 encoding, also for the table named "aat".

Workbench is giving me this error:

```
16:33:05 [INF][      copytable]: Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\xF1o' for column 'rdfs__label' at row 3:
```

**How can I migrate the PostgreSQL database succesfully to MySQL?**

Edit:
I created a PostgreSQL database with UTF8 encoding based on `template[0]`, but when I run
`\l template[1]` the Collate and Ctype is still Dutch_Netherlands.1252.

I also put this in my my.ini:

```
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server = utf8mb4
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
character_set_client_handshake = FALSE
```